# How to change specific element in row without reloading row in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch

I want to update a `UiSwitch` in a row in `UITableView`. I want to make it on and off with **animation** programmatically.

```
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:lastSelectedCardSectionNumber] retain];
    newCell *cell = (newCell *)[self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"newCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.switch1 setOn:YES animated:YES];
```

but the above line not changes the state and I have to reload row which doesn't make UiSwitch state change with animation.

---

There is a view on top of the switch which will user taps on it to change the state of switch. but it should be change just in some situations. Therefore I don't allow user to change it I want to change it programmatically.

Comment: how are you triggering this? on `didSelect` of `tableView`?

Comment: @hardikparmar I set a uiview on the switch to avoid switch state change by user. and when tapping on that view I someTimes(depends on some factors) change its state

Comment: put the whole code of how you retrieved `cell` in the Touch action of view. Also, have you checked that the action you set up in the view is getting called?

Comment: @hardikparmar Thanks. I updated my answer. yes it is called and when I write reload row method instead of setOn, it works but without animating the switch.

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: @hardikparmar Thanks. it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how you are retrieving the `cell`. It should be:

```
newCell *cell = (newCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

not this:

```
newCell *cell = (newCell *)[self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"newCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The former gets the already existing instance of cell but the later one creates the new instance of the cell.